# Cant import keras-rl in jupyter notebooks

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, keras-rl

I have been trying to import kera-rl into my jupyter notebook but i get this error every time i try.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rl'
```

How do I stop getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to keras-rl2 ,for more information on implementation 
check out this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaiqPPxq_5s&t=15s

Answer (score -2):

In the keras-rl repo you'll see a folder named `rl`. All the import modules you need are in here, to import you need to use `from rl.something import something`.

Check the [example folder](https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl/tree/master/examples) for multiple walkthroughs.

Comment: Please verify your installation. Recommend you to clone the repo and install